# Paypal Standard (express checkout) After success not return to the site

Tags: magento, paypal

We have two sites in magento

Both site have same paypal account.

but one site is working fine but another not.

Auto return is on in my paypal account

Site1.com is working fine its redirect to site1.com success page after purchasing

site2.com -- After purchasing at site2.com I don't get redirected back to site2.com Thank you for purchasing page. Remains at Paypal page.

Comment: A small trick to try: set "site2.com" into your PayPal account as the default auto-return URL.

Answer (score 0):

When request is posted to Paypal in that a return URL should get posted.

Log the form thats posted to Paypal aling with values and check whether it has that return URL or not.